# How to verify permission to update a specific column was granted?

Tags: postgresql

I have the executed following change:

```sql
grant update(speaker) on api.teams to anon;
```

How can I use a select statement to verify this change was made?

I can't see the entry in `information_schema.table_privileges`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriate view is [`informstion_schema.column_privileges`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-column-privileges.html).